# mongoose Foreign Key

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model called Portfolio that points to a user object using the user_id field. How can I model a many to one relationship with mongoose?

Portfolio 
  - user_id => is the id of a user object

Basically every portfolio object belongs to a user object.

I have the following code: Is this correct?

```
var PortfolioSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    url: String,
    createTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updateTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    user:[
      {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: The code above can be interpreted as a portolio belongs to a group of user... because of array notation

Answer (score 12):

Try this instead

```
var PortfolioSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    url: String,
    createTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updateTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    user:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
```